# How to cast parent class to child class in javascript

Tags: javascript, casting, box2d, box2dweb

I am working with [box2dweb](http://code.google.com/p/box2dweb/) and i am trying to make a function, that would add instructions how to draw a 'body' based on the 'body' shape.

That is: When received a 'b2BodyDef' get the shape, and with external information, get the shape specifications. To do this i need to cast 'b2Shape' back to 'b2CircleShape'.

I guess with C++ this would be something like

```
 b2CircleShape* shape_circle = dynamic_cast< (b2CircleShape*) >( shape );
```

How do i do similar thing with javascript? I do know there are tons of other ways to do this (like pass the wanted radius on this example as parameter) but i would like to do what i feel like right and not a hack.

```
function Add_new_drawable_object_to_world( body, type )
{
      GLOBAL_world_objects.push( body );
      var s = new Sprite();

      if ( type == OBJECT_TYPE_PLAYER )
      {
         s.graphics.beginFill ( 0x2222ff, 0.6);

         var b2CircleShape   = Box2D.Collision.Shapes.b2CircleShape;

         var fixture_list = body.GetFixtureList();
         var shape        = fixture_list.GetShape() ;

         // FIXME: TypeError: shape.GetRadius is not a function 
          var radius = shape.GetRadius();

         // here i would draw fancy circle with 'radius'
```

And earlier i have:

```
   // Create player
   var player     = new b2FixtureDef();   // ball fixture definition
   player.shape   = new b2CircleShape();
   player.density = 0.5;
   player.shape.SetRadius( 0.2 );

   var bodyDef = new b2BodyDef();
   bodyDef.type = b2Body.b2_dynamicBody;
   bodyDef.position.Set( 0.0, 0.0 );

   var body = GLOBAL_world.CreateBody(bodyDef);
   body.CreateFixture( player );

   Add_new_drawable_object_to_world( body, OBJECT_TYPE_PLAYER );
```

Comment: [JavaScript has no classes](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13418980/1048572). It has no strict types, and I doubt that you need to cast objects. What is `shape` actually, can you `console.log` it please?

Comment: Thanks @Bergi fast reply, the console.log shows:  
    [16:20:26.637] ({m_p:{x:0, y:0}, m_type:0, m_radius:0.2})

Is there way to call the function GetRadius somehow -- i would rather avoid touching the 'internals' of that class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Bergi says, Javascript has no classes so the concept of private/protected members does not really exist. I would suggest having a look at how box2dweb does this, because the debug draw display does almost the exact same thing you are doing here. Search for `b2World.prototype.DrawShape` in the box2dweb source.

If it makes you feel better, in the original C++ b2CircleShape the member variables are public, so there is no GetRadius and the 'internals' are accessed directly :)

Comment: For others finding this with google, the DrawShape is: `      case b2Shape.e_circleShape:
         {
            var circle = ((shape instanceof b2CircleShape ? shape : null));
            var center = b2Math.MulX(xf, circle.m_p);
            var radius = circle.m_radius;
            var axis = xf.R.col1;
            this.m_debugDraw.DrawSolidCircle(center, radius, axis, color);
         }
         break;`